# How the first word of the sentence to put in the span

Tags: php, string, laravel, replace, octobercms

I use laravel with blade. I do not know how the first word from record.title put in span. Does anyone know and can help me? Edit: I forgot the most important thing. This is a htm page from cms october

```
<h2><span>The</span> {{ record.title }}</h2>
```

Comment: You probably want to consider edge cases such as one-word sentences, e.g. *Amazing!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

October CMS is using the [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) template engine. you can do it in your template:

```
{{ record.title | split(' ')[0] }}
// for the rest of string 
{{ record.title[1:] }}
```

Comment: This will just display the first word, how about printing the rest of the sentence? Also, OP said he has simple HTML file.

Comment: final soluition

        {% set arrForTitle = record.title|split(' ', 2) %}
        <h2><span>{{ arrForTitle[0] }}</span> {{ arrForTitle[1] }}</h2>

again: thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the string into words thus:

```
$words = explode(' ',trim(record.title));
```

Then get the first one thus:

```
$first_word = $words[0];
```

Comment: I forgot the most important thing. This is a htm page from cms october

Answer (score 0):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create an array of words and [`str_after()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-str-after) to display all words after the first one:

```
@php $sentence = explode(' ', $record->title) @endphp
<span>{{ $sentence[0] }}</span>
{{ $str_after($sentence, $sentence[0].' ') }}
```

Comment: I forgot the most important thing. This is a htm page from cms october

Comment: @Piotr `explode` is PHP function. `str_after` is Laravel helper. So this should work in any template engine, you probably will need to use `<?php ?>` instead of `@php` if you don't use Blade. Have you tried this solution?

Comment: i try change file htm from October CMS to PHP. October do not accept php files. 

I try use <?php or @php but ... this file htm.

Comment: @Piotr I don't know what do you mean by HTML, because it can't be a simple HTML file. But you can create a helper like `spanFirstWord()` and call it from any part of your app to create an HTML ready string.

Comment: if you add new page in october cms you have htm files. October use twig, not blade. My fault, I'm sorry